# How to append a key before a value in Python dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a `dict`

```
x = {'[a]':'(1234)', '[b]':'(2345)', '[c]':'(xyzad)'}
```

Now I want to append the key before values, so my expected output is:

```
{'[a]': '[a](1234)', '[b]': '[b](2345)', '[c]': '[c](xyzad)'}
```

I can do it using `for` loop like below:

```
for k,v in x.items():
    x.update({k:k+v})
```

I am looking for efficent way of doing this or I should stick to my current approach?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Also, I'd recommend Code Review for improving programs that already work.

Comment: Python 3 stores key-value pairs in a list already. You can't get any faster than that because you can't skip over elements like you might be able to with sorting. Besides, reading values from an array isn't an expensive operation to begin with.

Comment: If the dictionary size is much larger, you could use `pandas` but for such a small dict size, the dictionary comprehension (answer by @yatu) is the best (and most pythonic) way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. @ParvBanks my dictinoary size is huge this is why I'm looking for alternative way and probably avoiding `for` loop

Comment: `pandas` would be the solution to both your problems. Let me try something...

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, I have posted my answer below. Please check if it works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach seems fine. You could also use a dictionary comprehension, for a more concise solution:

```
x = {'[a]':'(1234)', '[b]':'(2345)', '[c]':'(xyzad)'}

{k: k+v for k,v in x.items()}
# {'[a]': '[a](1234)', '[b]': '[b](2345)', '[c]': '[c](xyzad)'}
```

Comment: comparing both methods, this one is `0.000003` seconds faster

Comment: For the huge data it would matter though

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
x = {'[a]':'(1234)', '[b]':'(2345)', '[c]':'(xyzad)'}
dict(((key, key + x[key]) for key in x))
>>>{'[a]': '[a](1234)', '[b]': '[b](2345)', '[c]': '[c](xyzad)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For smaller size dictionaries, the `dictionary comprehension` solution by `@yatu` is the best.**

**Since you mentioned that the data set is large & you would like to avoid `for` loop, `pandas` would be the recommended solution.**

1. Create pandas dataframe from dict 'x'
2. Transform the dataframe & write to a new dictionary

**Code:**

```
# Read dictionary to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(x.items()), columns=['Key', 'Value'])

Out[317]: 
   Key    Value
0  [a]   (1234)
1  [b]   (2345)
2  [c]  (xyzad)

# Since the transformation is just concatenating both key and value, this can be done while writing to the new dictionary in a single step.
y = dict(zip(df.Key, df.Key+df.Value))

Out[324]: {'[a]': '[a](1234)', '[b]': '[b](2345)', '[c]': '[c](xyzad)'}
```

This would be much faster for large data sets but I'm not sure how to compare the timings.